# Can't compile Cmake project external library ( using GLWF (OpenGL))

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, glfw

I'm trying to compile a project to start learning OpenGL, but I can't.

When I run `CMake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` it generates the Makefile without any warning.
When running Make, it fails to compile. Here's the error raised.

```
fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` where I added the library.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
project(TEST)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

add_library(GLFW STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/GLFW/libglfw3.a )
set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external)

add_executable(hello ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(hello GLFW)
```

Here you can see my project tree:
[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JYaQ.png)

Do you have any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Change `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/GLFW` to this `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external` as the `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` directive already has has the `GLFW` part.

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried to change it and it still doesn't work. Before posting i also tried to just `#include <glfw3.h>` for this same reason and it didn't work aswell. Anyways, thank you, if you had any other suggestion let me know .

Comment: If you change something, and it still does not work, and you want help - you need to post the new error message as an update to the question.  If you get the same error then you have something else wrong as well.

Comment: I have edited your CMakeLists.txt suggestion. Error message still the same. Thanks

Comment: Could you try replacing the line `set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external)` by `target_include_directories(GLFW PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external)`. If it's still not working, could your provide the verbose commande line ? Run `make VERBOSE=1` to do so

Comment: The property `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` affects only on the comilation of the **target itself** (that is, in case of IMPORTED target this property is useless). For specify include directories for **users** of that target, set [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.htm)  property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

```
add_library(GLFW STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/GLFW/libglfw3.a )
set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external) # <- this line
```

I'm pretty sure you should be using [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) (which is for include directories added to targets that link to the target the property is specified on) instead of [`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) (which is for the target the property is specified on). Using `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` for an imported target actually doesn't make any sense, since it's imported- it's already built.

Note that you can also set include directories by using [the `target_include_directories` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html). Ex.

```
target_include_directories(GLFW INTERFACE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external")
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked and makes much more sense. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I made it work.

I was setting include directories on the GLFW target not the hello (main.cpp)

Changes to CMakeList.txt:

from

```
set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/GLFW/libglfw3.a )
set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external)
add_executable(hello ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)
```

to

```
set_target_properties(GLFW PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/GLFW/libglfw3.a )
add_executable(hello ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)
set_target_properties(hello PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external)
```

Thank you for you comments, helped me to figure out.

Comment: this is not a good solution. include directories should be specified on the targets that the headers are associated with. I'm writing up an answer now that I think will solve the problem in a better way.